# However Much You Explain Yourself

Tags: grammaticality

> However much you explain yourself, you are understandable to the extent they can understand.

Could you please check the quote translated into English?

Comment: Is there something in particular that you doubt?  We welcome almost any question about the language, but proofreading is not one of the site's purposes.

Comment: Yes, I wonder whether "you are understandable to the extent they can understand." is grammatically correct and makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder whether "you are understandable to the extent they can
>   understand." is grammatically correct and makes sense

"you are understandable" = people are able to understand you

"to the extent they can understand" = to the degree that they are able to understand

A paraphrase would be: "No matter what pains you may take to explain yourself, people will understand you only to the degree that they are able to understand."

In other words, their limited ability to understand will prove to be a limit on you no matter how much thought and effort you might put into your attempts to explain yourself to them.

Comment: Exactly. Out of respect for the Nobel Prize winning author who was teaching at Cal Tech at the time, I purchased a copy of *The Nature of the Chemical Bond* by Linus Pauling in the 1960s. I spent probably close to six hours over several weeks reading and re-reading the first four or five pages and finally gave up. As you put it so well, my limited ability to understand proved to be the limit no matter how much thought and effort Dr. Pauling had put into attempting to explain his subject (to me). I'm sure a chemist or physicist would find it easier going than I did, but I had hit the wall. +1

Comment: It is an quote, so how can we rewrite it in a shorter way?

"However much you explain yourself, they will understand you only to the degree that they are able to understand."

Comment: @Volcano - Yes, that is a clear sentence that captures the meaning of the original example. My only suggestion would be to substitute "comprehend" for one of the instances of "understand," just to avoid repetition. Well done.

Comment: Thanks. How about;

...... they will understand you only to the degree that they are able to.

Comment: You can make it very succinct and informal:  Explain away, but they'll get only what they get.